# working with templates in c++ calculator

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class A, class B >
A Sum(A Fnum, B Snum){
return Fnum + Snum;
}

template <class S, class W>
S Subtraction(S Fnum, W Snum){
return Fnum - Snum;
}
template <class M, class E>
M Multiplication(M Fnum, E Snum){
return Fnum * Snum;
 }
  template <class D, class C>
 D Division(D Fnum, C Snum){
return Fnum / Snum;
}
```

I am trying to do a calculator program to just learn about templates.I would like a little bit help with this the problem that I am having is - to plug in the numbers entered by the user as of what type?? What i was thinking was to do a case en prompt for 1 number ask what operation whant to do ex: +/-* etc and then pass those numbers to the functions... and return an answer regardless   if they enter 2 and than 2.567 or vice versa any suggestions?? are my template functions ok?? do they need any improvements..

Comment: One problem is that the return type is `int` if you pass `<int, double>`, but `double` if you pass `<double, int>`. You can use C++11 trailing return type syntax to avoid that: `template <class A, class B> auto Sum(A Fnum, B Snum) -> decltpye (Fnum + Snum) { return Fnum + Snum; }`

Comment: yep i have that in my already in case if i do the switch stament. and how do u know if its an int or double in this case its suppose to be generic.. i meant we don't know what the user will be typing right?

Comment: Unless you're feeling really ambitious, it's a *lot* easier to just do all the computation on, say, long doubles, and be done with it.

Comment: Well, if you're storing input to doubles in the first place, it won't matter, but if you happen to use the functions like I described without input, it would give possibly unexpected results. I guess it's more of a problem when there's no input involved.

Answer (score 1):

It might be safer to add two thing of the same type or class especially if the

```
T&  operator+( T number );
```

has been overloaded. If you are dealing with predefined types like

```
float, int
```

then you shouldn't worry, the code will work well. Try to make sure the arithmetic makes sense for what you want to get especially with multiplication and division.

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like :

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Add {
template < typename A, typename B > A operator() (const A & lhs, const B & rhs) { //note return type is A , what if A, B are diff? , you need promote one of them using specialization
return lhs + rhs;
}
};

//some other ops like above 

template < typename op, class A, class B > A operate(A Fnum, B Snum)
{
op oper;
return oper(Fnum, Snum);
}

int main()
{
int a = 20, b = 30;
std::cout << operate < Add > (a, b) << std::endl;
}
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/KReEQ